# R: Lookup value for calculation (similar to vlookup in Excel)?

Tags: r

I've got the following dataframes in R.

```
Name <- c("Tom", "Bill", "Jeffrey", "George", "David")
Value <- c("5.24", "5.48", "6.32", "6.07", "5.1")
df <- data.frame(Name, Value)
```

And:

```
Name1 <- c("Tom", "George", "David")
Name2 <- c("Jeffrey", "Bill", "Tom")
df2 <- data.frame(Name1, Name2)
```

I want to create another column in df2 which will produce the following:

Name1 * Name2 (based on value from df)

What is the best way to achieve this in R?
I know you can use vlookup function in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `match` to get the index for subsetting the 'Value' column use `Reduce` to do elementwise multiplication

```
# as Value is created with quotes, it is of class character
# use type.convert to change the column types
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
df2$Value <- Reduce(`*`, lapply(df2, function(x) df$Value[match(x, df$Name)]))
```

-output

```
> df2
   Name1   Name2   Value
1    Tom Jeffrey 33.1168
2 George    Bill 33.2636
3  David     Tom 26.7240
> with(df, Value[Name == 'Tom'] * Value[Name == "Jeffrey"])
[1] 33.1168
```

---

Or without `Reduce`

```
 with(df2, df$Value[match(Name1, df$Name)] * df$Value[match(Name2, df$Name)])
[1] 33.1168 33.2636 26.7240
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df2 %>%
  mutate(Value = across(everything(),  ~ df$Value[match(.x, df$Name)]) %>%
    reduce(`*`))
```

-output

```
   Name1   Name2   Value
1    Tom Jeffrey 33.1168
2 George    Bill 33.2636
3  David     Tom 26.7240
```

Answer (score 0):

using `tapply`:

first convert to numeric.

```
df$Value <- as.numeric(df$Value)
```

Then

```
df2$val <- tapply(df$Value[match(unlist(df2), df$Name)],row(df2), prod)

   Name1   Name2     val
1    Tom Jeffrey 33.1168
2 George    Bill 33.2636
3  David     Tom 26.7240
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
  left_join(df, join_by(Name1 == Name)) %>%
  left_join(df, join_by(Name2 == Name)) %>%
  mutate(mult = as.numeric(Value.x) * as.numeric(Value.y))
```

Result

```
   Name1   Name2 Value.x Value.y    mult
1    Tom Jeffrey    5.24    6.32 33.1168
2 George    Bill    6.07    5.48 33.2636
3  David     Tom     5.1    5.24 26.7240
```